# Cant write language specific caraters to database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I need to save text with language specific caracters in a mysql database.
I have setup the table and the field with utf8_general_ci
[image]

The test.php file to write into the database is also in utf8_general_ci:

```
<?php 

include 'connect.php';

$x=$_GET["x"];

$d="INSERT INTO `test` 
(`car`) 
VALUES (' $x ')";

echo $d;
$resultins = mysql_query($d);

echo mysql_error();
echo "<br>".$id;
?>
```

In the browser I do:

/test.php?x=Vietnam_ờ_French_ç_German_ä

and the echo gives:
INSERT INTO `test` (`car`) VALUES (' Vietnam_á»_French_Ã§_German_Ã¤ ')

In database I get:
[image]

When I retrieve this data in another php and display it in the browserI get:
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe before you start the select query, you should set the queries up to return UTF8 encoded string. First, use a `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the head and before the query try this: `mysqli_query($connection, "SET NAMES UTF8");`. Hope it helps.

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8"> does the trick. Thank you!

Comment: I accepted answer too quickly. With the meta the echo is showing correctly, but the database is still wrong.
When I add $connection->set_charset('utf8');
I get a Fatal error: Call to a member function set_charset() on a non-object

Comment: @michaelsmith What is the database character encoding? If it's in utf8_general_ci, it takes any kind of character.

Answer (score -1):

Place $dbc->set-charset('utf8') before any query.